# How rename child's id of expand listview (android)?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have a file.xml with structure for ExpandListView. How I can to rename child's id of List that id = 'name_child_0_1' etc ...

Answer (score 1):

I quite don't sure that is this will help you or not.

In your file.xml try to find (Am I correct that "file.xml" is your child layout?)

> android:id="@+id/name_child_0_1"

And then change it to what ever you want

eg.

> android:id="@+id/my_child_1"

Edit : To see which xml file used for child view, see in

> getChildView()

You will see that in [This turorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). There is

> convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

The "R.layout.list_item" is the xml file that is child list. (list_item.xml)

So, you can find id of child view inside of this file.

Comment: mmm... but id of child's ExpandableViewList generate are automatically ... or not?

Comment: I think you means ExpandableListView right ? The id of child list is defined by our self. So, please see this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/   I think it may help you.

Comment: Your welcome :D    Please see in the post, I already edited for more information about id of child in the method getChildView()